# ExtJS 4 with CakePHP - PDF showing in tab (mod_rewrite in webroot)

Tags: cakephp, extjs4, cakephp-2.2

I've created a PDF with TCPDF in app/webroot/files/Users.pdf. Now when I put an URL in browser I get a PDF downloaded and it works great.

But when I put the same URL in Ext-JS 4 in one `panel` I get:

```
No FilesController found
```

How can I disable mod_rewrite if I really want URL `/php/app/webroot/files/Users.pdf`?
Thank you very much. :)

This is the panel:

```
var tab = controller.tabs.add(Ext.widget('panel', {
                                    //icon: 'icons/doc_pdf16.png',
                        title: module,
                        layout: 'fit',
                        id: tabid+'Tab',
                        closable: true, 
                        items: [{ 
                                        xtype: 'box',
                                        autoEl: {
                                            tag: 'iframe',
                                            style: 'height: 100%; width: 100%',
                                            src: 'php/app/webroot/files/Users.pdf'
                                        }
                                    }] 
                                }));
```

**EDIT!**
URL CHANGED TO: src: 'php/files/Users.pdf'
Now it downloads it, but I want it to be rendered in my tab. Some headers or something? :)

Answer (score 1):

The decision between download and display depends on a header. So set the Content disposition to inline: header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="??.pdf"');